# Symfony2 / Firefox - session timeout giving error but stays in the page

Tags: php, session, symfony, firefox, session-timeout

I don't know how to explain it or what to call it. Suppose I am logged in. And at that time I shut down my browser without closing the page.

While I'm restarting the browser after a certain time to open the same page, it's getting an error. **It supposed to take me to the log in page if session is out rather it stays on the page** tries the ajax calls that are on my page and fails to do it. When I reload the page then it takes me to the login page.

What's wrong?? Why isn't it taking me to the login page at the starting of browser?

Let me know if you need to see any particular portion of code. I'm new to symfony2. Please explain why this is happening if possible!!

**Update**: Checked with Chrome, it's working as I wanted. But problem exists for firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Your browser is most likely loading the contents of that particular page from the cache. It's not making a call to your app server at all, so the server doesn't have the opportunity to tell your browser that the session is no longer active. This has nothing to do with Symfony in particular.

Comment: I know that browser is trying to open it from cache and not checking the session. That's the problem I mentioned. **But what's the solution?**

Comment: You could try adding a [Cache-control header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP_Caching_FAQ).